# New activity seemed to reset default but XML unchanged

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Can't figure this one out.

I added a second activity to a project in Android Studio. The second activity is now what launches on the emulator instead of the Main Activity.

Below is the XML in the manifest. Do I somehow need to declare the "get_started" activity as a child of the Main?

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".GetStarted"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_get_started"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just accidentally change `MainActivity`'s layout? That is, are you positive that the `GetStarted` class is actually what's being launched?

Comment: That I am positive of. Code is the same in  Main.

Comment: Are you maybe starting the `GetStarted` `Activity` immediately in `MainActivity`?

Comment: @Onik  is my terminology incorrect? MainActivity is my screen 1. GetStarted is my screen 2. On load, screen 2 loads.

Comment: the "emulator" got me confused... Now I seem I get it...

Comment: Oi.. Minus five brain cells for me.. You're right Mike M.  I set this startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GetStarted.class)); without an onclicklistener -.-   Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you run it from IDE (Android Studio) then you can select and activity to run. Check Run configuration. And what happens when you run your app from applications ins your smartphone, not with IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a DEFAULT intent filter to the MainActivity

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```